# Android how to relaunch previous running activities of my app

Tags: android, android-theme

I need to change the theme of my app using a button in settings page, my problem is when i change the theme i need to recreate the previous running activities to load new theme color and background images

any solution?

Comment: `recreate()` is the method that reloads your activity.

Comment: loads one view, i need to load previous running activities !!!

Comment: For that you can update your views in `onResume()` method

Comment: How?? `setTheme(R.style.theme)` doesnt works in onResume, just work before seContentView !!

Comment: `finish()` and then  `startActivity(getIntent())` in `onResume()` if setting has been changed.

Comment: startActivity in on Resume ?!! the activity will restart itself until infinity:)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `BaseActivity` that all your "refreshable" activities will extends, this activity will listen other activity result and recreate itself `recreate()` if needed (aka if other activity told to do so with intent data)

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity { 

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;  
    protected static boolean SHOULD_CASCADE_REFRESH = false;
    ...

    // Use this method instead of classic startActivity() one
    protected void customStartActivity(intent){
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    // Use this method to finish and cause refresh of paused activity
    protected void customFinish(){
        if(SHOULD_CASCADE_REFRESH) {
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
            resultIntent.putExtra("shouldRecreateActivity", true);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
        }
        SHOULD_CASCADE_REFRESH = false;
        finish();
    } 

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(REQUEST_CODE == requestCode){
            if(data.getBooleanExtra("shouldRecreateActivity", false)){
                // Magic is here
                SHOULD_CASCADE_REFRESH = true;
                this.recreate();   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your settings activity you have to set intent data according to wanted behaviour (refresh or not):

```
public class SettingsActivity extends BaseActivity {
    ...
    private void updateTheme(){
        SHOULD_CASCADE_REFRESH = true;
        // or 
        // SHOULD_CASCADE_REFRESH = false;
        customFinish();
    }

}
```

I tried it in a super simple case but I maybe missed some that side effects on your real app.